# Pooling messages before sending them to ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

The requirement is to send form data produced by website visitors over JMS (ActiveMQ most probably) from Tomcat. There are two competing ideas - one would utilize an intermediary store and a thread pool to send to the queue (and attempt resend if posting to JMS fails for some reason), and the other is to just try sending the payload directly over JMS from the thread that handles the visitors' post request - and fail the request if the JMS posting fails for some reason.

The second option seems better to me, as I think it is an overkill to add an intermediary store in front of a message queue - the message queue itself should be the intermediary store. Does that sound right?

Comment: Is there a requirement to pool the messages ? The subject line says so, but there is nothing about that in what you have posted. That said, what is the intent of pooling the messages ? The second option is the general way to go unless of course you are connecting over a (slow) network to the queue.

Comment: There is no specific requirement for pooling, but it came up during technical discussions as a reliability measure - e.g requests that eventually want to send messages could still suceed even if the MQ is down.
Seems to be an overkill to me, but just wanted to check if I am missing something.

Comment: I agree - design for normal use cases, account for edge cases in your design.

Answer (score 0):

What? Wait - A MQ Broker IS an intermediary (persistent) store to cope with downtime at the receiver side that can handle resend and what not. Non the less, you are somewhat right. You don't want to miss that order just because your (remote) broker is down. A resilient solution to that problem is to setup a local, possibly embedded ActiveMQ broker, then make a "network of brokers" connection to the remote broker. You can be sure that the local broker is up along with your webapp, and it will handle retransmission to the remote broker, if it happends to be offline for the moment.

I would, however, advice against implementing a simple in memory buffer to hold data until it can be posted to the broker.

Let's take a scenario (I'm just making up a purpose of the form):

1. User A orders a bike through the form and presses submit.
2. The bike order is put on the in-memory "pool" to be dispatched.
3. A message is returned to the user saying "thanks for your order, the bike will arrive soon".
4. The MQ broker is down for whatever reason.
5. Some time passes
6. The web server restarts because some admin found a nice patch that needs to be installed.
7. Order is gone as memory in the "redelivery pool" is scraped during restart.
8. A week later, the customer complains about the missing bike and your sales department has no clue what he is talking about.